# What type of bike do I have?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

[image]

We believe it is a 1960’s women’s 26” J.C Higgins from similarities I’ve seen online. Wanted to ask to see what value it may have

Misc. Pics 
[image]
[image]

Dae Young Tires
[image]

Comment: We don't do object valuations here.  Best I can say, absent any evidence that the bike is an unusually rare find, is "not much".

Comment: I appreciate the input, do you know anywhere else that may do what I’m looking for? Not too concerned with monetary value just got the bike for 10 dollars and wanted to see if there was any upside on it. Thanks again, Daniel!

Comment: Looks like a loverly bike - you or your nearest will enjoy riding it.

Comment: JC Higgins is a very good guess.  The style of the fork and the shape of the chain guard match images I find.  It likely had a "tank" when it was new.

Comment: (It's in very good condition for its age -- must have been stored indoors.)